# Unsubscribe to a firestore document snapshot listener

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to unsubscribe to snapshot updates for a listener I have put on a Firestore document? The documentation about this only shows how to unsubscribe to  snapshot updates on a `collection`. It says an `unsubscribe` function is sent back when the snapshot listener is set. However, it does not look thats the case for snapshot listeners on a document.
I dont get any unsubscribe function back, I only get an object that looks like this:

[image]

If it counts for anything, I am using the firebase emulator

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.  That log output is not helpful because we don't know what generated it.

Comment: Hi @DougStevenson, in the process of editing my code and copying it here to suit what you asked for, I think I found my answer. Lol! Thanks!

It looks like I rather stored my document reference in my "unsubscribe" variable, instead of what is returned from the real onSnapshot listener.

Answer (score 0):

The `onSnapshot` method returns a function that, when called, will unsubscribe:

```
const unsubscribe = firebase.firestore().doc('path/to/some/doc').onSnapshot(...);

// later
unsubscribe();
```